# App crashes when there is no internet

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

My app is an rss feed and retrieves data when started and when refreshed but when there is no Internet connection the app crashes. How do I check for Internet connection and display a toast if there isn't any

Comment: Check this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_network_connection.htm

Comment: refer [How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never timeouts...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Comment: lot of examples are their in google http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to check if there is internet

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

You also need to add this to the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

And then just check it

```
if(isConnected){
    //Connected to the internet
}
else{
    //Handle error and show toast
}
```

You can find a more detailed answer here 
[How to check internet access on Android? InetAddress never times out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts)

Answer (score 1):

To check is decive connected to network.

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
  ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

  return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
 }
```

To check if internet is avalaibe

```
public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("google.com"); //You can replace it with your name
            return !ipAddr.equals("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are missing the permission

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Check Internet connected or not

```
if(isNetworkConnected){

}
```

And add below permission in your manifestfile

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```